# css3 pop in and out animation that repeats once all have been shown

Tags: css, animation

I have a background image as a map. I want a list of testimonials (absolutely positioned divs) to appear and disappear one after the other on said map. Once all have been shown it needs to repeat.

How would I implement this using css3 animations?

Comment: share your written code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 animations and by delaying them you can create a full element animation, and then use JS setInterval to restart the animation. This is a commonly used way to do AdWords ads.

A good library with predefined animations is [animate.css](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/animate.css/) and you need to calculate the time all animations pass and are complete and set a interval that is removing the class and adding it back every time the animations are done(total time needed for all animations to be completed).

Answer (score 0):

a trick that i like to use is to iterate through each element you wish to show and offset the animation by a length of time * the element index. You could wrap this in a function and call it after time * element array length. This would effectively loop it forever. Some generic code based on half second animations would look like:

```
 function runThrough() {
        $('.your-elements').each(function(i,v) {
            var current = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() { 
                // do your animation e.g. $(current).fadeIn(500);            
            }, i * 500);        
        });
        setTimeout(runThrough(), $('.your-elements').length * 500 );
    }
```